# Why is building a Quarkus Microprofile application in version 1.10.5.Final fails with missing required class org/jboss/builder/item/BuildItem?

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to get my first sample application of Eclipse MicroProfile up and running bundled on a Quarkus 1.10.5.Final implementation but I'm missing something here because I can't get past the following below error that happens exactly on the execution of io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.5.Final maven plugin, build goal. Have you guys ever encountered this error before?

Pom file also added below alongside maven version.

If I change the quarkus.version property to 0.15.0, and remove the dependency version pom element of the "quarkus-smallrye-rest-client" dependency it builds fine.

Thanks in advance.

#### Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.5.Final:build (default) on project sample-svcs1: Execution default of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.5.Final:build failed: A required class was missing while executing io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.5.Final:build: org/jboss/builder/item/BuildItem
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.5.Final
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-maven-plugin/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-maven-plugin-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-core/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-core-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/commons-logging-jboss-logging/1.0.0.Final/commons-logging-jboss-logging-1.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logmanager/jboss-logmanager-embedded/1.0.6/jboss-logmanager-embedded-1.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-embedder/3.6.3/maven-embedder-3.6.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-connector-basic/1.4.1/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-transport-wagon/1.4.1/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http/3.3.4/wagon-http-3.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/3.3.4/wagon-http-shared-3.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3/jsoup-1.11.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.14/commons-codec-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/3.3.4/wagon-file-3.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-gradle-resolver/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-gradle-resolver-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-io/1.4.1/smallrye-common-io-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core-deployment/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-core-deployment-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/common/wildfly-common/1.5.4.Final-format-001/wildfly-common-1.5.4.Final-format-001.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/gizmo/gizmo/1.0.6.Final/gizmo-1.0.6.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.0/asm-util-9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.0/asm-tree-9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.0/asm-analysis-9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.2.1.Final/jandex-2.2.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.0/asm-9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-development-mode-spi/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-development-mode-spi-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-utilities/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-devtools-utilities-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.4/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-core-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/config/smallrye-config/1.9.3/smallrye-config-1.9.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-annotation/1.4.1/smallrye-common-annotation-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/config/smallrye-config-common/1.9.3/smallrye-config-common-1.9.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/microprofile-config-api/1.4/microprofile-config-api-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-expression/1.4.1/smallrye-common-expression-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-function/1.4.1/smallrye-common-function-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-constraint/1.4.1/smallrye-common-constraint-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-classloader/1.4.1/smallrye-common-classloader-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/2.1.0.Final/jboss-logging-annotations-2.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jboss/threads/jboss-threads/3.1.1.Final/jboss-threads-3.1.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-runner/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-runner-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-builder/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-builder-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/sdk/graal-sdk/20.2.0/graal-sdk-20.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-platform-descriptor-json/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-platform-descriptor-json-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-common/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-devtools-common-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-codestarts/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-devtools-codestarts-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-message-writer/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-devtools-message-writer-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/qute/qute-generator/1.10.5.Final/qute-generator-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/qute/qute-core/1.10.5.Final/qute-core-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/reactive/mutiny/0.11.0/mutiny-0.11.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-platform-descriptor-api/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-platform-descriptor-api-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/maven-model-helper/16/maven-model-helper-16.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1.3/jdom-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.11.3/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.11.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-websockets-jsr/3.0.16.Final/quarkus-http-websockets-jsr-3.0.16.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-core/3.0.16.Final/quarkus-http-core-3.0.16.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-http-core/3.0.16.Final/quarkus-http-http-core-3.0.16.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.49.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.49.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.49.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.49.Final/netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.49.Final/netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.49.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.49.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.49.Final/netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.49.Final/netty-handler-4.1.49.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-servlet/3.0.16.Final/quarkus-http-servlet-3.0.16.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jakarta/servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/4.0.3/jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jakarta/websocket/jakarta.websocket-api/1.1.2/jakarta.websocket-api-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.10.5.Final-1.10.5.Final.json
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-platform-descriptor-resolver-json/1.10.5.Final/quarkus-platform-descriptor-resolver-json-1.10.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jakarta/inject/jakarta.inject-api/1.0/jakarta.inject-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jakarta/enterprise/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api/2.0.2/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api-2.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jakarta/el/jakarta.el-api/3.0.3/jakarta.el-api-3.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jakarta/interceptor/jakarta.interceptor-api/1.2.5/jakarta.interceptor-api-1.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.25/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[82] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[83] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.6.3/maven-builder-support-3.6.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[84] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-util/1.4.1/maven-resolver-util-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[85] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[86] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.8.0/commons-io-2.8.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[87] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.1/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[88] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[89] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/30.0-jre/guava-30.0-jre.jar
[ERROR] urls[90] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[91] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
[ERROR] urls[92] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[93] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[94] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/2.1.0/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[95] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[96] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.10.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.10.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[97] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[98] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[99] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[100] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/jline/jline/2.14.6/jline-2.14.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[101] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.30/freemarker-2.3.30.jar
[ERROR] urls[102] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.json/1.1.6/jakarta.json-1.1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[103] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.3/jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[104] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.3/jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[105] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.3/jackson-core-2.11.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[106] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/2.3.1/mojo-executor-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[107] = file:/Users/l/.m2/repository/org/jboss/slf4j/slf4j-jboss-logmanager/1.1.0.Final/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.jboss.builder.item.BuildItem
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

#### Pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.packt</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-svcs1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.version>1.10.5.Final</quarkus.version>
    
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-metrics</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-opentracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-rest-client</artifactId>
       <version>0.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>native-image</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

#### Maven version

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_271, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_DK, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that causes the problem, but the dependency on `quarkus-smallrye-rest-client` is wrong and shouldn't be there at all. Instead, you want `quarkus-rest-client` (and no `<version>`, leave it to the version managed by the BOM). This is because the MicroProfile Rest Client implementation moved from SmallRye to RESTEasy.

Comment: @Ladicek Thank you for your reply and for your time. That's exactly right. The issue is now solved. The `quarkus-smallrye-rest-client` dependency was indeed wrong and it was the source of the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that!